# Please help how to solve that Problem No MODULE named markup://lighntning:card found : [markup://c:downloadCSV]

Tags: lightning-web-components

Simple Query

```html
<template>
    <Lighntning-card title="CSV Donwload">
        <template for:each={userdata} for:item="user">
            <div key={user.username}>
                <p>{user.username}{user.class} {user.Add}</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </Lighntning-card>
</template>
```

----------- JS Code----------------

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class DownloadCSV extends LightningElement {

    userdata = [
        {
            Username :"Dheeraj Sharma",
            Class:"MSC",
            Add:"Banglore"
        },
        {
            Username :"Manish Sharma",
            Class:"CA",
            Add:"Rohini"
        },
        {
            Username :"neeraj Sharma",
            Class:"graphic Designer",
            Add:"Budh Vihar"
        },
    ]
}
```

------------XML Code---------

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lighntning-card` should be `lightning-card`. Make sure you spell the words correctly, and use all lowercase.